# Как вывести только первую букву каждого слова в ловеркейсе?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, sed

`I Need To Print First Symbol For Each Word`

Необходимо получить:

`intpfsfew`

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что именно требуется. А если строка будет `World Cup 2018, Russia!!!`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew такой строки не будет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможное регулярное выражение:

```
\(\w\)\w*\( \|$\)
```

и его применение в команде `s` (эдитора `sed`):

```
s/\(\w\)\w*\( \|$\)/\1/g
```

---

Применер:

```
$ echo "I Need Print First Symbol For Each Word" | sed 's/\(\w\)\w*\( \|$\)/\1/g'
```

Вывод:

> ```
> INPFSFEW
> ```

(Когда вам на выводе нужны *строчные* буквы, смотрите на Замечание в конце ответа.)

---

Разбор регулярного выражения:

```
(\w\)\w*\( \|$\)
```

- `(\w\)` - подхват первой буквы слова (как первой группы)
- `\w*` - ноль или более остальных букв в слове
- `\( \|$\)` - пробел ( ) или `(\|)` конец строки `($)`.

---

Разбор команды `s`:

```
s/\(\w\)\w*\( \|$\)/\1/g
```

Совпадение с этим регулярным выражением (находящемся между *первым и вторым* символом `/`), то есть *слово с пробелом или концом строки* ...

... заменится  первой подхваченной группой (`\1`) (находящейся между *вторым и третьим* символом `/`) - значит *первой буквой слова*.

В конце команды `s` флаг `g` (global), чтобы заменилось *не только первое совпадение* (слово) первой буквой, но *все*.

---

**Замечание:**
Когда на выводе должны быть *строчные* буквы, примените `\l` или `\L` (lowercase - строчные буквы) перед заменой на первую подхваченную группу (`\1`):

```
$ echo "I Need Print First Symbol For Each Word" | sed 's/\(\w\)\w*\( \|$\)/\L\1/g'
```

Вывод:

> ```
> inpfsfew
> ```

Comment: Да, спасибо большое! Немного добавил, и получил что надо: ```echo "I Need Print First Symbol For Each Word" | sed 's/\(\w\)\w*\( \|$\)/\1/g;s//\L&/g'
``` - Благодарю!

Comment: Такое решение работает только в GNU sed, `\w`, `\s` не поддерживаются традиционными POSIX BRE/ERE.

Comment: У меня GNU, предложенный вариант отработал как нужно. Вывел первую букву каждого слова в ловеркейсе.

Comment: тоже работает: `'s/\(.\)\w*\W*/\l\1/g'`

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить такой вариант: `\b[a-zA-Z]`