# sed - выдача только первых букв каждого слова строки с сохранением регистра

Tags: linux, sed

Нашел похожую тему [Как вывести только первую букву каждого слова в ловеркейсе?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/844119/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B5)
Однако, предложенные там варианты не всегда работают, если требуется выдать первые буквы с сохранением регистра буквы оригинала.
Например работает (это тот возврат, который требуется получить ( не DW и не dw ):

```
echo "Dont worry" | sed 's/\(\w\)\w*\( \|$\)/\1/g'
Dw
```

Однако, если есть апостроф в слове или знаки препинания сразу после слова, то код не работает:

```
echo "Don't worry!" | sed 's/\(\w\)\w*\( \|$\)/\1/g'
Don'tworry!
```

Как исправить? Удалить сначала все знаки препинания? (апостроф под них все равно не попадает).

Comment: Апостроф в коллекцию [[:punct:]] попадает.

Comment: да, Вы правы, попадает, немного напутал с кодом сначала, `sed 's/[[:punct:]]//g;s/\(\w\)\w*\( \|$\)/\1/g' ` в принципе работает, но может кто предложит что-то проще? Есть варианты без удаления знаков препинания?

Comment: 2 вопроса. Можно ли как-то конкретизировать задачу? (нифига не понял что из чего нужно получить. возможно уже голова не варит). Обязательно ли использовать sed для решения?

Comment: Да, нужен только sed. Из `"Don't worry!"` получить `Dw`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вот так как-то. \w - "буква", заменил на \S - "не пробел"

```
echo "Don't worry" | sed 's/\(\w\)\S*\( \|$\)/\1/g'
#Dw
```

Но кажется что вот так:

```
echo "Don't worry" | sed -E 's/(\w)\S+(\s+|$)/\1/g'
```

Будет корректней. Иначе если у Вас окажется между словами не один пробел а (на пример) 2 или знак табуляции то не сработает. Да и выглядит почитабильней.

Comment: Да! спасибо) So easy